# selecting one textarea from multiple textareas generating by mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have many textarea in my code generating by a mysql query and given the id by the result of this query

```html
<div class='examples form-group margin-bottom-none'>
  <div class='col-sm-9'>
    <textarea class="mention form-control input-sm" id="reponse" placeholder="Essayer de taguer quelqu'un en tapant @nom" rows="1"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-2'>
    <button class='get-syntax-text btn btn-danger pull-right btn-block btn-sm' id="add" id2="<?php echo $row['id_proposition']?>" type="submit">Comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like on click on the `get-syntax-text` button selecting only this textarea, or the code that i have select all the textareas that i have

```js
$('.examples .get-syntax-text').click(function() {
  var id_prop= $(this).attr('id2');
  alert(id_prop);  $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput('val', function(text) {
    var response=text;
    alert(response);
  });
});
```

How i can select only one textarea giving the id by a mysql query when i click on `get-syntax-text` button

Comment: Have you tried using an id selector?

Comment: I'm beginner on jquery, how can i use id selector?

Comment: Go to the jquery site and follow one of their tutorials!!! Seriously why do people try to use a language without finding the basic usage information first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding function func_site_editing(){} onclick to "html" 
the , false pending on code may or may not be needed. it keeps the listener from initially firing per say.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("site_editing").addEventListener("click",func_site_editing, false));    
}
```

folks tend to replace event with e, and/or evt for shorthand.
the with event and then .target returns what was clicked, and then the .id returns the id of the html element

```
function func_site_editing(event){
    var myvalue = document.getElementById(event.target.id).value    
    //console.log(event.target);
    //console.log(event.target.id);
    //console.log(myvalue);
}

this
this.id 
vs
event
event.target
event.target.id
```

i am not up to date enough to say other, but seems "this" was over used. in previous years. and event.target is more wanted / used. and in that you no longer need to irritated (using for loops) to find what initiated a given function. due to "event.target" gives you that specific information.

Answer (score 1):

$("#lastname") - id selector

$(".intro") - class selector

$("p") - element selector

visit for more options: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp